# Should I use 'health check' or 'healthcheck'?

Tags: word-choice

I don't know if this adds anything, but the context is computer software where a component checks the health of the system and produces a report.

I don't know whether it's a 'Health Check Feature' or a 'Healthcheck Feature'.

I don't know why, but 'healthcheck' seems more natural in the sentence 'I'm running a **healthcheck**',  whereas the the other version seems better in the sentence 'the results of the **health check** were...'

Comment: Dictionaries have it as "health check": http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/health%20check?s=t
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/health-check?q=healthcheck

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=administration-system-health-check-tool https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/how-to-use-the-pc-health-check-app-9c8abd9b-03ba-4e67-81ef-36f37caa7844 https://aws.amazon.com/builders-library/implementing-health-checks/ https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000189290/how-to-run-pc-health-check-for-microsoft-windows-11-upgrades

Comment: Google Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=healthcheck%2Chealth+check%2Chealth+-+check&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use "health check".  The compound word "healthcheck" is not common.

This compound word may sound more natural to you because there *is* a common compound word used in this setting with almost the same meaning: "checkup".

To see why "health check" is better, try replacing those two words with two  words that have similar grammatical and semantic roles: "disk test".  Would you say "I'm running a disktest"?  I think not.

Answer (score 0):

In IT it's healthcheck, in other relations it's health check. It's ironic that Microsoft being an IT company for so long would default to correct it to health check, but I suppose the client base holds larger non-IT populous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's a tendency to smush words together in IT, but Microsoft has a [PC Health Check app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/how-to-use-the-pc-health-check-app-9c8abd9b-03ba-4e67-81ef-36f37caa7844), IBM has a [System Health Check tool](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=administration-system-health-check-tool) and [this software engineering SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312687/what-should-be-the-scope-of-a-health-check-for-a-system-which-deploys-a-webapp) mostly uses "health check".